# Consuming wcf service with webrequest getmethod giving 404 error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, wcf-binding

Im Calling My WCF WebService With Http WebRequest. Its Working Fine But When I Pass Some Special Character in Parameter It Gives Error 404. Page Not Found..

Here is My Code Snippet.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "Data/{username}/{password}")]
        string RequestData(string userName, string password);
    public string RequestData(string userName, string password)
        {
             // Here is My Logic Comes

         }

// Here im Calling This Service in My ASPX Page 

HttpWebRequest req = null;
            HttpWebResponse res = null;
            try
            {
                const string url = "http://localhost:53366/AuthService.svc/Data/test@test.com/password#1"; // Here Gives Error 404 Page Not Found

//const string url = "http://localhost:53366/AuthService.svc/Data/test/password"; // Here Works Fine When I Pass This Paramters Without Special Characters
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "Get";
                req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

                req.Headers.Add("AppID", "MobileApplication");

                res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                txtTokenRespoonse.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                streamReader.Close();
                streamReader.Dispose();

                responseStream.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass any special character to URL you must encode it!

Try:

```
const string url = "http://localhost:53366/AuthService.svc/Data/test%40test.com/password%231";
```

Btw. passing password in URL is just a sample, isn't it?